# jquery slideshow effect

Tags: jquery, slideshow, effects, jquery-effects

This effect can be found in jquery plugins for slideshow?

```
http://www.rotapanel.com/trivision-anime/trivision_anime.swf
```

such as: Nivo Slider, ColorBox, Slides, Coin Slider, ...

If not found, Can it be simulated?

thanks, inmoon

Comment: you have lot of jquery plugins for lots of effects..

Comment: I want exactly the trivision effect, Is there such a thing?

Comment: Never seen it. The nearer I know of is called "billboard effect", like this : http://tympanus.net/codrops/2009/12/16/creating-a-rotating-billboard-system-with-jquery-and-css/

Comment: did you google and search more for that..

Comment: got that stuf

http://www.littlewebthings.com/projects/blinds/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got that stuf

http://www.littlewebthings.com/projects/blinds/

the above one is good and same

Get these stuff and make its effects

http://jqueryui.com/docs/Effects/Methods#Basic_Effect_Transition

below are some of them listed not exactly but

http://workshop.rs/projects/jqfancytransitions/

http://www.malsup.com/jquery/cycle/browser.html - best for you chosse `Grow X` effect